# google-map web component NoApiKeys error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polymer

I am use a `google-map` web component:

```
<google-map class="mdl-shadow--2dp"></google-map>
```

To which I am later adding a latitude and longitude as part of an ajax return and resizing to show it:

```
$('google-map')[0].latitude = data.latitude;
$('google-map')[0].longitude = data.longitude;
$('google-map').resize();
```

All this works fine. Recently I noticed in the console that I am getting the warning

> Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

I got a key and tried specifying it as an `apiKey` property of the `google-map` component per [the documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map) like:

```
<google-map class="mdl-shadow--2dp" apiKey="MY_API_KEY"></google-map>
```

but to no effect. What am I missing?

Comment: If you use Javascript, Do you add in your post, your javascript code ? (the line <script src=""></script> for Load your gmap API.

Comment: I already included all the JavaScript I'm using. I'm guessing including a script is done under the hood of the `google-map` web component? All I do is change the latitude and longitude and resize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when the documentation says `apiKey` is the property name, they really mean `api-key`. This works:

```
<google-map class="mdl-shadow--2dp" api-key="MY_API_KEY"></google-map>
```

Comment: Just to add, [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping) is this link to the docs explaining this.

Comment: Thanks for that @BenThomas!